# В консоле не видно Vagrant

Tags: консоль, vagrant, scope

[image: Вагрант установлен, доступа из консоли к нему нет, в чем проблема?]

Вагрант установлен, доступа из консоли к нему нет, в чем проблема?

Comment: Это powershell, а не консоль...

Comment: исчерпывающе...